# Proof that $K_{3,3}$ is non planar using Euler's formula.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm struggling to understand the proof that $K_{3,3}$ is nonplanar. Using Euler's formula we know that $3f \leq 2e$. The proof goes like this: 
If we had drawn the graph in the plane, there would be no triangles: this is because in any triangle either two wells or two houses would have to be connected, but that is not possible. So, summing up the sides of every face we get $4f \leq 2e$. **I don't understand where the 4f comes from**.

Why is it that every face has at least four edges?

Comment: 3,3 thank you for the correction

Answer (score 2):

As $K_{3,3}$ is a bipartite graph, each face is bounded by an even number of edges, so at least four. If there are $f$ faces, then the total number of edges
in their boundaries is $\ge 4f$, but that total number is $2e$ as each edge
is in two faces, so $2e\ge 4f$.

Comment: but I don't understand the triangle all the way to the left has only three edges, yet it is a face

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see it now, the face I'm talking about is not actually a face because the intersection of the two lines does not contain a vertex. Correct?

Comment: @MatteoCiccozzi Which triangle and where is left? There is no triangle in a bipartite graph

Comment: Lets say we have u1, u2, u3 connecting to v1, v2, v3. We then have the following edges that form a triangle (or so I thought) {u1, v1}, {u1, v2}, and {u2, v1}

Comment: @MatteoCiccozzi Perhaps confusion arose because one should make clearer distinctions: The edges of a *graph* (as abstract object) do not intersect. In a *planar embedding of a graph*, the arcs that represent the edges *might* intersect - but then again, if they do, we do not actually have a planar embedding. - And $K_{3,3}$ can readily be "drawn" in 3D space